# SSL certificate not working for www subdomain on multiple domain setup

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, ssl-certificate-errors, www

I have a LAMP server running CentOS Stream 8 and Apache 2.4.37. On this I have three domains (let's call them example.com, example.net & example.org). I have SSL certificates for each domain + the `www` subdomain.

They share the same codebase (the only difference being the defalt langauge) so they share the same `/var/html/www` folder and there is no specific domain level configuration in the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file - the `ServerName` is `example.org:80`

I do have a specific configuration in the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file. Here following is the relevant excerpt - there's a `<VirtualHost *:443>` part for each domain.

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName example.com:443

ErrorLog logs/ssl_example_com_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_example_com_access_log
LogLevel warn

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/example_com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example_com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

The SSL certificate for each domain works for the main domain, but only works for the `www` subdomain of example (which is the first listed) in the `ssl.conf` file. So if I try to access https://www.example.net or https://www.example.org, I get a `Connection not secure` and `Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead` from the browser.

What works:
https://example.com
https://example.net
https://example.org
https://www.example.com

What doesn't work:
https://www.example.net
https://www.example.org

I cannot find any hint as to what could be happening in the logs. Does anybody have an idea where I could be looking?

I've tested and whatever domain's `VirtualHost` section is listed first is the one for which the `www` SSL works.

Comment: Have you check the CN (Common Name) of certificate itself?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @EsaJokinen

Comment: @RomeoNinov _Common Name_ (CN) won't have both the apex and www covered at the same time, so checking it isn't quite helpful.  It's the _Subject Alternative Name_ (SAN) extension that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the certificates are correct, there certainly is a detail in your configuration that explains this behaviour. From Apache [Virtual Host Matching](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html#hostmatching), the emphasis is mine:

> If the connection is using SSL, the server supports Server Name Indication, and the SSL client handshake includes the TLS extension with the requested hostname, then that hostname is used below just like the Host: header would be used on a non-SSL connection. **Otherwise, the first name-based vhost whose [IP] address matched is used for SSL connections.** This is significant because the vhost determines which certificate the server will use for the connection.

Your `<VirtualHost *:443>` blocks are missing [`ServerAlias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) directives for the `www` subdomains. Therefore, the first `VirtualHost` is used as a default name based virtual host, instead.

Furthermore, the [`ServerName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) could be used without the optional `[:port]` as there is no need to distinguish the virtual hosts by ports.

Also notice that [`SSLCACertificateFile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcacertificatefile) is for client authentication:

> This directive sets the *all-in-one* file where you can assemble the Certificates of Certification Authorities (CA) whose *clients* you deal with. These are used for Client Authentication. Such a file is simply the concatenation of the various PEM-encoded Certificate files, in order of preference.

The filename `example_com.ca-bundle` suggests you might have confused this with (deprecated) [`SSLCertificateChainFile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile); since 2.4.8 the [`SSLCertificateFile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile)

> may also include intermediate CA certificates, sorted from leaf to root.

An example with a [macro](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_macro.html) that can reduce the copy-paste configuration as well as handle the redirects from HTTP to HTTPS:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<Macro VHost $domain $tld>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName $domain.$tld
        ServerAlias www.$domain.$tld
        Redirect permanent / https://$domain.$tld/
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName $domain.$tld
        ServerAlias www.$domain.$tld

        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

        ErrorLog logs/ssl_$domain_$tld_error_log
        TransferLog logs/ssl_$domain_$tld_access_log
        LogLevel warn

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/$domain_$tld.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/$domain_$tld.key
    </VirtualHost>
</Macro>

Use VHost example com
Use VHost example net
Use VHost example org
```

Comment: Brilliant, this worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: I noticed another potential problem and updated my answer to cover it.